# How to validates JSON type in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I want to validate my response type as a JSON in RSpec, but `respond_with_content_type` is no longer available in `shoulda-matchers`.

Reference: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/252

I'm using:

- rails (4.0.2)
- rspec-rails (2.14.1)
- shoulda-matchers (2.5.0)

This is my controller:

```rb
class BrandsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @brand = Brand.new(permitted_params)
    if @brand.save
      render :json => permitted_params, :status => 200
    else
      render :nothing => true, :status => 500
    end
  end

  private 
  def permitted_params
    params.require(:brand).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

And this is my spec:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe BrandsController do
  describe 'POST create' do
    context 'with empty data' do
      before(:each) { post :create, brand: { name: '' } }
      it { should respond_with 500 }
    end
    context 'with invalid data' do
      before(:each) { post :create, brand: { name: '123' } }
      it { should respond_with 500 }
    end
    context 'with valid data' do
      before(:each) { post :create, brand: { name: 'somebrand' } }
      it { should respond_with 200 }
      # should respond with JSON type
    end
  end
end
```

Any hints will be great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
expect(response.headers["Content-Type"]).to eql("application/json; charset=utf-8")
```